# Read from a newly created file

Tags: go

I want to write some stuff on a newly created file

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, _ := os.Create("temp.txt")

    contents := "some stuff..."

    f.WriteString(contents) // <--------
    f.Sync()

    //f.Close()
    //f, _ = os.Open("temp.txt")

    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    fmt.Println(string(b))  // <--------
}
```

but after writing some stuff and then reading, the last line print nothing. why?

if i uncomment those two lines above, everything works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from or write to a file you move the current position, so it continues reading/writing from where you left. There is only one position, so if you write and then read, you start reading from where you're left after you write.

Use `f.Seek(0,0)` to move the position to the beginning of the file after you write.